# add phones to a csv file from raw to clean

Tags: python, pandas

Im using python to get a list of emails from a google search.
I can extract phones ike this

```
 # Phones
phone = re.findall(r'[\+\(]?[1-9][0-9 .\-\(\)]{8,}[0-9]', snippet.lower())
phones.append(phone)
```

in the "raw file".
When i'm creating the clean file, i get only emails, but not phones.
this is the code

```
order_selection = data[['raw_url','email','phone']].drop_duplicates().dropna()


order_selection['email'] = order_selection['email'].astype(str).str.replace(r"^[][\s]*$|(^\[+|\]+$|')", lambda x: '' if x.group(1) else np.nan , regex=True)


order_selection = order_selection.drop_duplicates().dropna()


### GROUP BY PART
groupby_order_selection = order_selection.groupby('raw_url')['email'].apply(list).to_frame().reset_index()

groupby_order_selection['email'] = groupby_order_selection['email'].astype(str).str.replace(r"^[][\s]*$|(^\[+|\]+$|')", lambda x: '' if x.group(1) else np.nan , regex = True)


groupby_order_selection = groupby_order_selection.drop_duplicates().dropna()
```

any idea where i should add the phone code?
thanks!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample of your data and the matching expected output

Comment: im getting this in the raw file
query porgescakes.com/ @ email
email ['info@porgescakes.com']
phone ['845-782-1130']
raw_url https://porgescakes.com/

but in the clean file i get only
raw_url and email
thanks!